# Trying to Automate Opening of Excel File and then flowing that data into Power BI (Used Selenium to web scrape exported xls file)

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, powerbi

I have code using `selenium` that successfully exports an `xls file` from my desired website. Once the `xls file` is downloaded I am unsure how to use `selenium` to open the file. Once this data gets opened and downloaded I would like it to automatically be flowing into `Power BI`.

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Selenium. It's plain vanilla to directly access a web based Excel file with Power BI. This is what Power BI is made for.

However, if you already have an Excel file locally, I'd suggest you upload it to Onedrive and import it into Power BI from there. And once your report is in the Online service you can directly refresh it via schedule or trigger.

Importing the Excel file from disk is not the recommended way of doing things unless it's a one-off.